# No sé cómo usar la función PROMPT dos veces y guardar los resultados

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el que llevo atascado ya demasiado tiempo. El ejercicio en cuestión dice:

Utilizar la función *prompt* para generar un cuadro y recoger su el valor introducido con la función *return*, has de hacer esto 2 veces.
Explico, tengo los valores Peso y Altura que he de introducir mediante la función *prompt* y recoger los datos con *return*, pero cuando uso la función *return* la segunda función *prompt* nunca se activa, he probado a meterlo todo dentro de una función a la que llamo mediante un evento *onclick* pero tampoco funciona, sinceramente estoy perdidísimo y atascado, ya no soy ni capaz de ver en que puedo estar fallando.

Lo que ahora estoy intentando es esto:

```
   function myfunc() {
    var prompt("Introduce tu peso.","0");
    
    return;
}
```

Siento la mala redacción o si no me he explicado apropiadamente, estoy empezando y es mi primera vez preguntando por aquí.

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Actualización:

```
var person = {
    altura:"",
    peso:""
}
function data(){
    function alerta(){
        let prompt("Introduzca altura","0");
        let prompt("Introduzca peso","0");
    }
    return alerta() 
}
```

Tengo esto y parece funcionar, pero no sé si es correcto.
PD: tengo que utiliza las funciones *prompt()* y *return* obligatoriamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código con el que has intentado resolver el problema, no importa que no funcione, solo así podemos tratar de ayudarte a encontrar el error.

Comment: Perdona, ya está no sé si eso es suficiente o he de poner el código entero de lo que estoy haciendo, he intentado evitar esto último porque necesito ayuda, no me que me solucionen el ejercicio entero.

Comment: No es suficiente, por favor edita la pregunta nuevamente para poner el código que ejecuta esa función que, por cierto, tiene error, debes asignar el resultado de `prompt()` a una variable.

Comment: Algunas cosas que debes saber: `var` es para declarar variables globales. Usa `let` para locales. El `return` no es necesario si no devuelve nada. Y ¿por qué no escribes prompt una vez más? Así el prompt aparecería 2 veces

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta: cuidado con el uso de funciones como `prompt()`, `alert()` o `confirm()`. Hubo polémica hace unos meses porque Chrome las consideró "obsoletas" y dejaron de funcionar en algunos casos después de una actualización.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como los valores son peso y altura podemos generar un objeto persona que tenga a esas propiedades.Asi conservar los datos en un objeto y operar con ellos .Te muestro como se puede devolver a un objeto desde una funcion lo cual en realidad en este ejemplo no seria necesario ya que tu funcion no retorna nada y lo dejo como comentario ya que luego de darle valores en la funcion se puede acceder a ellos muy facilmente en cualquier parte del codigo

```js
const person ={
  peso:'',
  altura:''
}

    function myFunc() {
    person.peso = prompt('Cual es tu peso?') ;

    person.altura = prompt('Cual es tu altura?')  ;

   }
    
     myFunc();
     console.log( `Peso: ${ person.peso} altura ${person.altura}`)
```

> Sin usar objetos una posible solucion seria:

```js
function myFunc1() {
 let peso = prompt('Cual es tu peso?');

return peso



 }
 function myFunc2(){
let altura = prompt('Cual es tu altura?');
return altura
 }

let peso=myFunc1()
let altura=myFunc2()
console.log( `Peso: ${ peso} altura ${altura}`)
// o mostrarlos en cajas de texto
//document.f1.f1t1.value = peso;
//document.f2.f1t2.value = altura;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

</head>
<body>
  <form name="f1" id="f1">
    <input type="text" name="f1t1" id="f1t1">
     
  </form>
  
  <form name="f2" id="f2">
<input type="text" name="f1t2" id="f1t2">
  </form>
  <script>

//person =new(Object);
const person ={
               peso:'',
               altura:''
              }
function myFunc() {
person.peso = prompt('Cual es tu peso?');

person.altura = prompt('Cual es tu altura?');

//return person
 }
//data=myFunc()
   myFunc()
   document.f1.f1t1.value = person.peso;
    document.f2.f1t2.value = person.altura;
   // document.f1.f1t1.value = data.peso;
   // document.f2.f1t2.value = data.altura;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cuidado que en el primer snippet le estás asignando un valor a person sin haberlo inicializado antes. Por otra parte, en la función myFunc, o bien no es necesario devolver el objeto, ya que el mismo es creado en el scope anterior, por lo tanto tendría acceso al objeto person sin necesidad de que lo devuelva la función, o idealmente el objeto person se crea e inicializa dentro de la función.

Comment: es evidente lo que decis como puse en la respuesta uso el return simplemente porque el en su solucion tenia un return para que vea como se puede  se puede devolver a un objeto desde una funcion igual lo edito y aclaro

Answer (score 3):

Inicialmente en el código que muestras no estás obteniendo la respuesta del **prompt**.

Para poner el código exacto se necesitaría más contexto, pero quizás esto te sirva.

Ejecuta este snippet y verás que sucede:

```js
function getPeso() {
  return prompt("Introduce el peso: ");
}

function getAltura() {
  return prompt("Introduct altura: ");
}

function getData() {
  var peso = getPeso();
  var altura = getAltura();

  //hacer algo con las variables, validación y escenarios de uso
  console.log("Peso " + peso);
  console.log("Altura " + altura);
}

getData();
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).